# pptpd - address already in use

Tags: networking, server, vpn, pptp, pptpd

I am trying to use `pptpd` to setup a VPN server. When I run the following

```
service pptpd restart
tail /var/log/syslog
```

The log contains the following error

```
MGR: Couldn't create host socket
createHostSocket: Address already in use
```

I figured out that this is related to ports. Including the following lines in `/etc/services` solves the error

```
pptp 11723/tcp
pptp 11723/udp
```

However, I want to use the port `1723` instead of something else. Are some other services blocking the port?

Result from `netstat -ln | grep 1723`:

```
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:1723  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a port is already used, you can use `lsof`:

```
↳ lsof -i :1723
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
netcat  31521  mikael    3u  IPv4 374307      0t0  UDP *:1723
```

In the above example, I just started `nc` to listen for UDP connections on port `1723`.

You can also get information about a process listening on a port with `netstat`:

```
↳ sudo netstat -lptun | grep ":1723"
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723        0.0.0.0:*                31729/netcat
```

So you need to figure out what service is already using `1723` and probably consider using a different port for `pptpd`.